# Grails: using java class from controller

Tags: java, grails

*UPDATED

I am new to grails and stack. I am trying to instantiate a java class in a controller. My .java file is in the /src folder. I have tested the class outside of grails and it works fine. However, when I try to instantiate it from a controller I get a null pointer exception. My relevant code:

```
package matrices

import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

class MFController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def index() {
        MatrixFactorization m = new MatrixFactorization()
        def answer = m.getAnswer().toString()
        return answer
    }
```

My trace:

```
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   45 | run       in matrices.MatrixFactorization
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     36 | <init>    in     ''
|     10 | index . . in matrices.MFController$$ENtqy0Aa
|    195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

MatrixFactorization class 35-45

```
public MatrixFactorization() {

double[] l1 = { 5, 3, 0, 1 };

double[] l2 = { 4, 0, 0, 1 };

double[] l3 = { 1, 1, 0, 5 };

double[] l4 = { 1, 0, 0, 4 };

double[] l5 = { 0, 1, 5, 4 }; //45
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You list the `index` method, but it looks like the failure is in the `list` method.

Comment: in addition to the list() method, please post the source of the MatrixFactorization class, as the stack trace indicates that the error is at  line 45 in that class' source. Please also indicate which line is #45

Comment: 1. Do you have your Java class under src/ or src/java. Should be the latter.
2. Is the Java class in a package? I am assuming matrices because your code snippet doesn't show an import. I have experienced issues with accessing classes in the default package. Try putting it under a test package, if not already, and then import it in your controller.

Comment: Its path is src/java/MatrixFactorization.java uchamp. It has no package statement in it. I updated the trace: I had accidentally pasted the trace of a previous version of the code in which the same code that is now in 'index' was in my 'list' method. Sorry for the confusion. I will try the test package advice.

Comment: Ahh yes. Thank you. When I used a package for MatrixFactorization.java and imported that into my controller, it fixed my issue. Perhaps you should make your package suggestion an answer to recieve credit uchamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad this worked for you. Here's the comment posted as an answer too.

Is the Java class in a package? I am assuming matrices because your code snippet doesn't show an import. I have experienced issues with accessing classes in the default package. Try putting it under a test package, if not already, and then import it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at line 45 in the `run` method of the `MatrixFactorization` class as the 1st line of the stacktrace shows. The class is instantiating fine, but it's failing internally. Is there some missing configuration or setup before calling `getAnswer()`?